# compare array and json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, diff

http://jsfiddle.net/0czdrn7t/4/

I try to compare two array ,

find object(`Type` = 4) in array `arrayB` and if all object(`Type` = 4) `Privilege` not match the `arrayA` value, then insert to `arrayC`.

for this example the `arrayA[0]` is 1 already match in `arrayB` last object then I don't want it push into the result, want's wrong with my code??

```js
var arrayA = [1];

var arrayB = [ { Type: 1,
        Privilege: 0,
      },
      { Type: 3,
        Privilege: 0,
      },
      { Type: 3,
        Privilege: 1,
      },
      { Type: 4,
        Privilege: 1,
      } ];


var arrayC = [];

var type = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
  var insertValidate = true;
  var issetTypeValidate = false;

  for (var ii = 0; ii < arrayB.length; ii++) {
    if (arrayB[ii].Type == type) {
      if (arrayB[ii].Privilege != arrayA[i]) {
        insertValidate = false;
        // break;
      }
      
      issetTypeValidate = true;
    }
  }

  
  if (issetTypeValidate == true) {
    if (insertValidate == true) {
      var o = {};
      o.Type = type;
      o.Privilege = arrayA[i];
      arrayC.push(o);
    }
  } else {
    // var o = {};
    // o.Type = type;
    // o.Privilege = arrayA[i];
    // arrayC.push(o);
  }
}

console.log(arrayC);
```

Comment: use alert(JSON.stringify(prepareInsertRoleList)); instead of console.log(prepareInsertRoleList);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `updateRoleList[ii].Privilege != inputUserRoleType4[i]` returns `false`
when `updateRoleList[ii].Privilege` equals to `1` and `inputUserRoleType4[i]` is also `1`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
      var arrayA = [1];

    var arrayB = [ { Type: 1,
            Privilege: 0,
          },
          { Type: 3,
            Privilege: 0,
          },
          { Type: 3,
            Privilege: 1,
          },
          { Type: 4,
            Privilege: 1,
          } ];


    var arrayC = [];

    var type = 4;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
      var insertValidate = true;
      var issetTypeValidate = false;

      for (var ii = 0; ii < arrayB.length; ii++) {
        if (arrayB[ii].Type == type) {
          if (arrayB[ii].Privilege == arrayA[i]) {
//          alert(arrayB[ii].Privilege +'='+arrayA[i])
// if at least one of them is equal, than don't print it
            insertValidate *= false;
            }
        issetTypeValidate = true;
        }
      }

      if (issetTypeValidate == true) {
        if (insertValidate == true) {
          var o = {};
          o.Type = type;
          o.Privilege = arrayA[i];
          arrayC.push(o);
        }
      } else {

      }
    }


    alert(JSON.stringify(arrayC));
```